An installed program has been deleted by someone - how to find their identity?
13 days ago I asked about how to uncompress files downloaded from the arXiv math site, and I got the following response:
Downloading from the arXiv site and uncompressing
I downloaded files from the 7-zip site and as I comment in the thread: It did install on my computer.
Now it appears the installed program from the 7-zip site has vanished from my computer. How do I check the login history of this computer and how do I find the identity of the person/user that deleted the 7-zip program from my computer? I'm not an expert in the windows-7 operating system and I'm asking for advice from an expert.
Is there a way to install a program on the computer that registers all activity on the computer?

This information is by default not logged. Enabling a log of who logged in is possible, but not easy and not detailed, but also not turned on by default. Finding out who uninstalled it is going to be even harder.

@LPChip  - is there a way to install a program on the computer that registers all activity on the computer?

Sure, I bet if you google about this, you can find more about it. Keep in mind, that the program may have been uninstalled by some process. For example, an update that went wrong or something like: you activated a restore point from before 7zip was installed.

If experts could comment on what keywords I should use in a google search and what is the best programme(s) available on the market, this would be of great help.

Try the following steps. Not sure if it works on Windows 7. You will need to check every entry unless you know the date when the application you removed.

Be aware that security on Windows 7 is low, and a knowledgeable user could work around any logging or restrictions on installing and removing apps. That is a poor choice of OS, considering support for it ceased years ago.
